# Space between 2 words

Tags: html, css

im trying to create space between $366 and Bekijk fiets on the button. i tried d-flex justify-content-between but that didnt work out.

```html
<div class="container my-container mt-5 ">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 justify-content-center">
       <div class="col mb-4 ">
         <div class="card h-100" style=" border-radius: 1rem; box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
           <img src="Fiets1.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
           <div class="card-body">
             <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
             <p class="card-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link text-center align-items-center " style="width: 100%; height: 25%; border: solid rgb(49, 6, 117); background-color: rgb(49, 6, 117);">$366,    -Bekijk fiets</a>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For giving spaces u can try &nbsp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

space-between would only work if you had the 2 text parts as 2 individual elements, for example 2 span-elements. You could use this:

```css
.spaced{
  word-spacing: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spaced">
first second
<div>
```

I would only do this tho if you have to write the words into the same element. Otherwise i would do this:

```css
.button {
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
<span>first</span>
<span>second</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `&emsp;` entity to provide spaces between texts if you don't want to use css.